# Reset only the settings for HTC One

Tags: settings, factory-reset, htc-one

I have an HTC One (4.2.2) & I need to reset my settings ONLY, just the settings.
Is there any way not to lose my data, without making a backup?
I mean I want a factory settings for the settings only.
Thanks.

Comment: You could go to *Settings->Apps*, switch to the "All" tab, and walk the apps you want to reset the settings. Apart from that, there's only the factory reset AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

Goto Settings-->Apps-->All-->(`you can find Settings App`)click on Settings--> Clear data and cache